# Ambivalent encoding of BeautifulSoup object constructed from website with duplicate meta header. How do I make sure the encoding is not mixed up?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, encoding, utf-8

I have fetched data from a website using `BeautifulSoup` module. I know from meta header that the source encoding for this document is 'iso-8859-1'. I also know that `BeutifulSoup` automatically transcode to 'UTF-8' upon creation of `BeautifulSoup` object.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/12/cri/2003-2004/20040001.asp"
r=requests.get(url)
soup_data=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

print(soup_data.prettify())
```

Unfortunately, the website has a duplicate  element.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Upon inspection of the `BeautifulSoup`  object using prettify, I realized that `BeautifulSoup` converted only one of these meta tags.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-eqiv="Content-Type"/>
```

I'm therefore confused what is the actual encoding of my `BeautifulSoup` object.

Also, during data processing I realized that some of text elements of this object are not properly parsed by my PyCharm console. These strings are 'iso-8859-1' code characters. Therefore, I suspect that the object is either still in ISO encoding or even worse, somehow mixed up.

`['\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0M. le président.' '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0M. le président.'`

I have seen these ISO characters for the first time after I run a numpy function.

```
series = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x[0].get_text(), 0, [df])
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed from this situation? I would like to convert the object to UTF-8 (and be 100% sure it's fully in UTF-8).

Comment: Assuming Python 3 those strings are already decoded to Unicode code points. `'\xa0'` is U+00A0 NON-BREAKING SPACE. The string isn’t encoded at all. `b'\xa0'` (note the b) is the *byte* 0xa0 encoded in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I have now used "from_encoding='Windows-1252'" as in your answer, but the '\xa0' is still being printed out instead of non-breaking space. Any suggestions why this character is still not correctly shown?

Comment: In a list, a debug representation of a string is shown. It’s so you can tell the difference between an ASCII space and a no-break space. If you `print` the strings in the list individually, it will show as a space instead of an escape code.

Comment: Indeed, I realized that these '\xa0\' code point appears in lists, but don't appear in strings. What is baffling to me thought, is that it's not always the case. Some lists (all from the same source) show this code point and other lists don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` used the `ISO-8859-1` encoding to decode the `r.content` (a `bytes` object) into Unicode (a `str` object).  A `str` is not encoded at all.  It is made of of Unicode code points.

It turns out the data wasn't encoded in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).  It was encoded in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), a similar encoding with a few extra translations (see the hyperlinks for each).

The `requests` response indicates the encoding the website used (`r.encoding`) and the apparent encoding using its detection code (`r.apparent_encoding`).  Here are some differences in the actual text I found:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/12/cri/2003-2004/20040001.asp"
r=requests.get(url)
print(f'{r.encoding=}')
print(f'{r.apparent_encoding=}')
print()
soup_data=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
print(repr(soup_data.find('a',href="http://www2.assemblee-nationale.fr/scrutins/liste/(legislature)/15/(type)/AUT").text))
print(repr(soup_data.find('a',href="#",accesskey="0").text))
print()
#Using the correct encoding
soup_data=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml', from_encoding='Windows-1252')
print(repr(soup_data.find('a',href="http://www2.assemblee-nationale.fr/scrutins/liste/(legislature)/15/(type)/AUT").text))
print(repr(soup_data.find('a',href="#",accesskey="0").text))
```

Output.  Note the `\x85` and `\x92` code points in "censure…" and "d’accessibilité" in the first instance.  The `…` (U+2026) and `’` (U+2019) code points don't exist in ISO-8859-1 and the bytes 0x85 and 0x92 translate to U+0085 and U+0092 respectively which are unprintable control codes.  I've used `repr()` to show them as escape codes.

```
r.encoding='ISO-8859-1'
r.apparent_encoding='Windows-1252'

'Autres scrutins solennels (déclarations, motions de censure\x85)'
'Politique d\x92accessibilité'

'Autres scrutins solennels (déclarations, motions de censure…)'
'Politique d’accessibilité'
```

Answer (score 0):

To **ensure** that you are using the correct encoding, you could use `EncodingDetector` packaged with `bs4`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector

url = "https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/12/cri/2003-2004/20040001.asp"
r = requests.get(url)

encoding = EncodingDetector.find_declared_encoding(r.content, is_html=True)
soup_data = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml", from_encoding=encoding)

print(soup_data.prettify())
```

Comment: I know the the actual encoding from the meta header. I tried your example, and it doesn't change anything. The two meta headers in the prettify's print still show ambivalent information and the post-processing string still show some ISO characters.